# Intuition for regularity of solution of this hypoelliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider
$$
u_t + (x-y)u_{x}+yu_{y}-u_{yy}=-xy+x^2+|x|.
$$
I figured out that the left hand side is a [hypoelliptic operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172053/verification-of-the-hormander-condition) because the vector fields $A_0:=\partial_{t}+(x-y)\partial_{x}+y\partial_{y}$, $[A_0,A_1]= \partial_{x}-\partial_{y}$ and $A_1:=\partial_{y}$ are linearly independent in $R^{3}$ (triangular with ones on the diagonal). Therefore, solutions would be smooth if the right hand side didn't contain $|x|$. Unfortunately, I don't have a good intuition about the effect of that term.

Could anyone with experience handling such PDEs make an educated guess/prove something about the regularity of solutions?

I am really only interested in the particular term $|x|$, not in $|y|$ or $\|(x,y)\|$.

This is partly a reference request, but please don't link to anything behind a pay-wall, if possible.

Comment: Hypoellipticity is a local property. Thus you would have smoothness in the sets $\{x > 0\}$ and $\{x <0 \}$. Also, any two solutions differ by a smooth function, again by hypoellipticity. Therefore you need to find (guess?) a particular solution.

Comment: @Hans Do you have a guess at the smoothness of the transition?